# Mount and unmount directory on service startup

Tags: server, mount, mysql

I am running ubuntu and a mysql database instance. There is an encryption key stored currently just on my /var/secretkey directory. From suggestions on the internet I see people mount a directory on mysql startup that contains this key file, and then when the system is up the directory gets unmounted. I am unsure though how to actually implement this. Currently, to start my server I use systemctl start mysqld. I looked for some sort of configuration parameter in the config file for a mount point or something similar, but couldn't find anything. I am not too familiar with linux, but essentially I just want to somehow mount the directory when mysql starts up and then unmount once it has started. I am also open to any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Run `man mount` and also research the `/etc/fstab` config file. After you absorb those ideas, it should empower you to write a wrapper script that executes the desired commands.